# System Information with DOS

Tags: dos

I have just brought new laptop with DOS OS.
I am trying for system information to check my new laptop details, but unable to check.

I have used commands 'sys', 'HWiNFO'. 
Can anyone tell me how can I check my all system information.

Thanks.

Comment: How to go in superuser? I have just turn on my new laptop

Comment: This is not a forum for helping people using their computer, its a programming forum. Goto "superuser" forum

Comment: Click on the stackexchange logo at the top left and scroll down a bit

Comment: In plain MS-DOS there really isn't anything. You can enter `ver` to find out what version of MS-DOS you're using and `mem` to find how much memory is available.

Answer (score -3):

You could try command:  systeminfo